# Alternatives to "reboot" after changing crucial files in a working server?

Tags: linux, centos, reboot

Assume I have a server already functioning and providing an app to users. At one moment, I have to modify some crucial /etc/ configuration files. For example, /etc/security/limits.conf.
After I do the changes, documentation usually suggests rebooting the machine.

```
reboot
```

But this would imply that all processes in the server die, am I right? So, basically what will happen to the guys checking my app hosted on the server that I just "rebooted"? I think the service will stop for a while. Is there any other command or alternative less painful to do after changing crucial files?

I'm on CentOS & Nginx.

PD: If somebody could provide also a link to the difference between "shutdown" and "reboot"  (because I found only some vague things), that would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy part first - if you run shutdown your computer ends up being off. As in no power. As in, very difficult to fix remotely :). Reboot restarts everything.

It is fairly rare to require a reboot under linux - the only reason to reboot that I can think of is if you upgraded the kernel, if your machine is crashing really badly, or if you want to install some types of new hardware (RAM, plug-in cards etc).

Mostly, when you edit "important files in /etc", you can restart just a part of the system. For example, you might need to restart just your webserver.

There is no complete rule. Try googling "reload ". For example, googling "reload /etc/security/limits" suggests logging out, then logging back in.

Comment: thanks man no more reboot